# Modify large graph DSE Datastax

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I want to go over every node and calculate the number of connections of that node.
Is there a way to go over the nodes in a distributed manner ? I have around 50 million nodes

Thanks
Cristi

Comment: Run your gremlin query in analytics mode.

Comment: Thanks For the answer. I need to update each node. For example I ned for a person node to find if his address is shared with other persons. Can you point out a simple example ? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like it will be a Gremlin query which will iterate over the entire dataset.  From a DSE Graph server perspective, it is recommended to issue this Gremlin query using the Analytics mode as you're going to execute a full graph traversal.  Please reference the TinkerPop documentation for the correct approach to the Gremlin syntax.  There are several recipes which may assist you in your traversal design contained in the TP documentation.  http://tinkerpop.apache.org Also, you can use the Academy Slack room for faster answers- https://academy.datastax.com/slack

Comment: Yes, you are right. How can I issue a Gremlin query using Analytics to execute a full graph traversal ? Thanks.
This is not working
g.V().hasLabel('person').match(          _.as("a").out('has_address').in('has_address').count().as('address_count'))
              .select("person_id","address_count")